Which expressions do you find the most suitable in this data report?
This is the first time I've used the writing site of Stack Exchange.
I'm writing a data report on the percentages of males and females playing different sports in the UK. The data for males and females were similar in all three categories:

tennis: 7% of males, 7% of females
 basketball: 7% of males, 6% of females
 jogging: 4% of males, 5% of females

As a non-native speaker, I've spent the last thirty minutes struggling to wrap all this up in one sentence (as there's a word limit in this essay). I want to point out that: (1) the figures for males and females are similar and (2) all of the figures are below 10%. Here's my attempt:

The figures for males and females were similar in three categories—tennis, basketball, and jogging—all below the 10% mark. (The main problem with this sentence for me is that I'm not sure if I'm using the emdash correctly. Also, I don't know if calling these sports "categories" is weird, but I suppose I can't say "in all three sports" either.)

Do you think this sentence conveys my intention? Do you have any advice for me?

Personally, I think the word "similar" doesn't convey the accuracy of the data correctly.
In all three sports, the figures are within 1% of each other. Saying "under 10%" reduces the accuracy.
I'd say

In all three sports (tennis, basketball, jogging), male and female participation was 4% to 7%, and in each sport within 1% of each other.

Yes,  the em-dash is used correctly.


Differend kinds of sport are called disciplines.

You used the em-dash correctly.

If you were interested in both the comparision between groups and the abolute numbers, I would consequently both say that the numbers are similar and what the numbers are (e.g. "below 10%"). If your study was only interested in either the comparison or the absolute numbers, I would either state that they are similar or what the numbers are.

Why did you choose to summarize all numbers as "below 10%"?

If you want to avoid having to list all the individual numbers, I would rather say that all figures were between 4 and 7 %.
If you have defined 10% as the threshold of significance, then I would rather say that all figures were not significant.

In any case, if your intention was to compare genders and disciplines, you must list the individual numbers either in text or in a table. You should only give a summary result if there is a table that shows the individual group results. If there is no table, you must give those numbers in text.
If, on the other hand, the comparison between groups is irrelevant, don't calculate them separately.


So, all taken together, your sentence could read something like:

The figures for males and females were similar in three disciplines—tennis, basketball, and jogging—, all between 4% and 7% (see Table 4).

or:

The figures for males and females were not statiscially significant in three disciplines—tennis, basketball, and jogging (see Table 4).

or:

The figures for males and females were similar in three disciplines: tennis 7% of males, 7% of females; basketball 7% of males, 6% of females; jogging 4% of males, 5% of females.

Note the lack of a reference to a table in the last example, implying that there is none.
